# What is the meaning of the invariant $S^{ij} S_{ij}$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I came across $S^{ij}$ when studying GR and Riemann Curvature.

$$S^{ij} = \oint_{\text{loop on the surface}}  x^i dx^j - x^j dx^i \approx \text{Area Enclosed By The Loop.}$$

What is $S^{ij} S_{ij} ?$

And does this mean something like "area" in any coordinates or does this have to be done in cartesian coordinates to give "area".

I used this to parameterize a circle and find the area.

Then I calculated it in polar coordinates by doing the integral such that $x=r$ and $y=\theta$ and by transforming the tensor and got the same answer, $2\pi r$. And that's not an area.

Comment: It is hard to tell what is $S_{ij}$ without further information. Can you provide some reference where you found this notation?

Comment: Just a comment: you cannot say $x = r$ and $y = \theta$. You already made this mistake in a previous question.

Comment: Moreover, the area is an instrinsic object and does not depend on a coordinate choice. What you wrote is (by Stokes formula) twice the area enclosed by the loop, written in Cartesian coordinates.